# Printing lines in a format in java

Tags: java

So my project is to implement paging, recalling that paging is unlike swapping which allows the memory of a process to be broken up in frames. My only problem is the structure I have to print this. So the char which are 'A4' , 'E4' as such given these are examples but are processed which 280 frames. So the char are stored in a String[] memory. I have to print these memory which like stated is 2 string char of a alp and a number.
It needs to look like this when done:

```
        04        09        14        19        24        29
--------++--------||--------++--------||--------++--------||
A1D5F7E5E3R3Q1Q2R5Y7A1D5F7E5E3R3Q1Q2R5Y7A1D5F7E5E3R3Q1Q2R5Y7
        31        33        35        37        39        41
--------++--------||--------++--------||--------++--------||
A1D5F7E5E3R3Q1Q2R5Y7A1D5F7E5E3R3Q1Q2R5Y7A1D5F7E5E3R3Q1Q2R5Y7
```

So the top is increments of the location of the string array showing only the 5th one starting at 00.
then we just have -------++------ just for looks I guess.
And then the last line is that of the String[] memory and what is in that array.

This is what I have so far:

```
    public static void printpmem(String[]memory, int colm, int increment){
    //true for memory
    //This prints the stuff in the memory
    int call = 0;

    printloc(0);
    printstuff();
        for (int i=0; i < MAX_FRAMES; i++)
        {
                System.out.print(memory[i]);
                colm++;
                if (colm == 120)
                {   
                    System.out.print("\n");
                    colm = 0;
                    call++;
                }
        }
}
    public static void printstuff(){
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.print("--------++--------||--------++--------||--------++--------||--------++--------||--------++--------||--------++--------||--------++--------||--------++--------||--------++--------||--------++--------||--------++--------||--------++--------||\n");
    }
    public static void printloc(int loc){

        for(int showloc = 0; showloc<MAX_FRAMES; showloc++)
        {

            increment++;
            loc++;
        if (increment == 4)
        {
            System.out.printf("     %02d      ", loc);
            increment = 0;
        }
        if (showloc == 120){
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
        if (showloc == 240){
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
        }
    }
```

This is the output I get which I cant get it right at all. Please Help!

```
     04           08           12           16           20           24           28           32           36           40           44           48           52           56           60           64           68           72           76           80           84           88           92           96           100           104           108           112           116           120      
     124           128           132           136           140           144           148           152           156           160           164           168           172           176           180           184           188           192           196           200           204           208           212           216           220           224           228           232           236           240      
     244           248           252           256           260           264           268           272           276           280      
--------++--------||--------++--------||--------++--------||--------++--------||--------++--------||--------++--------||--------++--------||--------++--------||--------++--------||--------++--------||--------++--------||--------++--------||
R7L9F5B2R6J9C9A6F3E5F6A1A6D4C9G6L6J9I8H5A1A1K2U4F6A6R7A1G6B2C3B5H3R7K1R6C3E5G6H5G6N2C3N2L6L6O2A6P3H5E7G6G6X3C3E5T8F5H5U4J9B2P3F6A1K1K1U4R2Z3L6T8G6F5E5E7O2X3L6A6B5M1M1O2J9H5Z3T8G6O2T8B5F3A1B2O2A1I8F5B5G6R2C3C9E5B2T8R6G6K2B2T8F5J9R6N2N2R7U4U4
L6I8C3F5X3F5P3M1N2F5A1H5E7D4H7V6J9A1A1E5A1F6R7Y5L6C9C2H7W8C2U4M1W8C3C3C2F5L6B5H5V6B5T8L9H3E7O2G6I8D4B2I8T8A6L9K1D4C9K1H3H7H3R7L9T8C3F5C9R7C9F5K1B5C9L6R7C2F3J9G6G6H7H3A6X3A6K2G6M1I8A1C3K1B2X3K2C2R7D4H3E5O2L9T8H3Z3R7G6E7R7L6M1G6H5R2E7X4X3I8Y5
```

Its a little off the width of the line should be 120 long. So 60 elements. Putting it on the website makes it look ugly.

So is there a way I can set a line to a var then go back to that line to fill in more? Im just not sure how to do this.

How can I go about printing this in the order show? Starting with:
 location of array incrmenets show of 5
these stupid dash things -------++++
then the actually string array of elements

Answer (score 0):

You can't *go back* to a line once it has been printed.  What you can do is use the same size field for all of your numbers so they line up properly.  The simplest would be to replace `%02d` with `%04d` (and adjusting spaces as necessary); this will handle up-to-4 digit numbers.

If you need all numbers to be at least 2 digits (w/ a leading 0 if necessary), but no more than that if not needed, you can use `%4d` if the value is > 99, and `%02d` (with two leading spaces) otherwise.

Comment: My only problem with that is it has to be 2 digit numbers I cant make it more then that.

Comment: But you have a lot of 3-digit numbers being displayed!

Comment: MY problem is getting it to first print the numbers then the ----- and then the actually stuff in the array. But only 60 elements before it goes to next line and does numbers again and so forth.

Comment: But im saying I cant have any more zeros is what I mean

Comment: so the first one has to be 04 then no more zeros

Comment: so if I use the %4 then it adds zeros to the start

Comment: `%4d` does not have leading zeros.

Comment: Yes but I need leading zeros on the 04 and the 09 then it dosnt really matter lol

Comment: My biggest problem is just printing these in order then reprinting for the next set